# Vue devtools do not show setup with vite and TS

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite, devtools

The project is built with Vite 4.4.5 and using vue 3.3.4 and Typescript 5.0.2.

I use the  component syntax: I don't have the setup section in the Vue Devtools anymore.

[image]

I created another blank project and I have the setup section: **It is not the Devtools plugin or the version that are the cause.** I tried to copy the package.json, the vite.config.js and the tsconfig.ts files from one project to the other to spot the differences but I does not work.

Is anyone has a clue ? A config problem or a cache to rebuild ? Here are the vite.conf.ts files:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

const path = require("path");

export default defineConfig({
  base: "/v3/",
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/": {
        target: "https://dev.ns.eu",
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
    extensions: [".mjs", ".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".json", ".vue"],
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
});
```

The package.json

```
{
  "name": "nvue3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --mode development",
    "build": "vue-tsc && vite build --mode development",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/tracing": "^6.19.7",
    "@sentry/vue": "^6.19.7",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
    "copy-text-to-clipboard": "^3.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.30.2",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-clipboard3": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-gtag-next": "^1.14.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.1",
    "vueup": "^1.3.0",
    "vuex": "^4.1.0",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "6",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.3.4",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5",
    "vite-plugin-dynamic-import": "^1.5.0",
    "vitest": "^0.31.3",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.5"
  }
}
```